# Изменяем права потока

Tags: delphi

Помогите написать исходник, чтоб давал приоритет потоку (или всем потокам) при вводе процесса. Пример - ввожу `explorer.exe`, если есть такой процесс, дает всем его потокам приоритет - `hThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL`. Помогите, плс, кто шарит, и ссылочку на исходник...

Comment: "Помогите, плс, кто шарит" - подозрительно звучит. На практике знаю, что обычно те кто употребляет эту фразу - безнадёжны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно

```
SetThreadPriority(MainThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
```

где:

- `MainThread` = `HENDL` процесса
- `THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST` = приоритет

Comment: а как получить PID процесса? и сможешь сделать исходник и залить куда нить, был бы сильно благодарен =)

Comment: Вам же давали ответ в Вашем же вопросе по потокам.
По моему Вы взяли высокую планку, может с начала потренеруйтесь на Hello Word ?
Да и ГУГЛЬ отвечает на 90% Ваших вопросов

Comment: Если вам недостаточно моего примера, может быть пока рано заниматься этой темой?

Comment: И, кстати, там первым параметром не pid, а хэндл.

Comment: Ага, поправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно получить хэндл процесса функцией [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), а потом уже просто задать ему приоритет при помощи [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx).

ЗЫ. В конце не забыть вызвать `CloseHandle`, конечно.